# How to loop over objects and push the keys into an array?

Tags: javascript

I have an object which consists of `newSales` and `oldSales` and I am looping over them to get the key value pairs.  I have been able to console log them but now I am stuck.  How do I push those key value pairs in my array?  This is a sample [codepen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/pooKPOw?editors=1111)

```js
const obj = {
  newSales: 1,
  oldSales: 0,
  anotherProp: 'something',
  etc: 'etc',
  values: 'numbers'
}

function myDataSet() {
  let dataSet = []
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(`${key} : ${obj[key]}`)
      dataSet.push({
        name: ['newSales', 'oldSales'],
        data: [1, 0]
      })
    }
  }
  return dataSet
}

myDataSet();
```

The new Name in the object should be the `name` i.e. `newSales` and `oldSales` and `data` inside should be an array with the values 1 and 0. I appreciate all the help.

Expected output:

```
[ { name: ['newSales', 'oldSales'], data:[ 1,0 ] } ]
```

Comment: So the final result will be: `[ { name: "newSales", data: [1, 0] }, { name: "oldSales", data: [1, 0] }]`. That doesn't make sense

Comment: BTW, since you only have one object and since that object only contains 2 properties, why do you need to loop it in the first place? Just construct the result directly using literals

Comment: My bad. the final result will be: ```[ { name: ['newSales', 'oldSales'], data:[ 1,0 ] }```. Thank you for pointing that out. I Should have been more clear.

Comment: Yeah actually it consists of a lot more properties, actually let me fix the code above.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I fixed the code, hopefully it's a bit clear now. Thank you.

Comment: One final thing, does it have to be an array that contains only one object `[ { ... } ]`? Why can't the result simply be that object `{ ... }`?

Comment: So the object is going to be pushed in an array andthat object would contains it's own set of arrays with name and data in it. Hopefully i explained it well.

Comment: if you need one object only then why do you loop?

Comment: @IronyStack Then how can i construct the resulting data myself? Honestly i only care about the newSales and oldSales property.

Comment: @Somethingwhatever look at my answer then, you need loop if you have other properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want something line this

```js
const obj = {
  newSales: 1,
  oldSales: 0,
  anotherProp: 'something',
  etc: 'etc',
  values: 'numbers'
}


  let dataSet = [], names= [], data =[];
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && ["newSales", "oldSales"].indexOf(key) >= 0) {    
      console.log(`${key} : ${obj[key]}`)
      data.push(obj[key]);
      names.push(key);
    }
  }
  dataSet.push({names:names, data:data});
  
console.log(dataSet)
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, you want this.

Edited to have the outer array as required, although I don't understand its purpose.

```
let dataSet = [{
  name: Object.keys(obj),
  data: Object.values(obj)
}];
```

Comment: yes, but both name and data should be in their own array.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: ```[ { name: ['newSales', 'oldSales'], data:[ 1,0 ] } ]```

Comment: It should match that now.

Comment: JS objects do not guarantee property iteration order. That means that key-value pairs may break up (your code may result in `[ { name: ['newSales', 'oldSales'], data:[ 0,1] } ]`. Note that the values are swapped)

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) "The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property names, in the same order as we get with a normal loop." and "The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well)." Shouldn't that keep them aligned?

Comment: The purpose of doing this was because i am trying to construct a horizontal bar chart using chart js and i wanna construct a dataset from this object and pass that onto chart js with labels being New and Used and the data being the values ```[0,1]```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of an object's keys by calling [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), similarly for values:

```js
const obj = {
  newSales: 1,
  oldSales: 0
}

function myDataSet() {
  let dataSet = []
  dataSet.push({
    'name': Object.keys(obj),
    'data': Object.values(obj)
  });
  return dataSet;
}

console.log(myDataSet());
```

Comment: JS objects do not guarantee property iteration order. That means that key-value pairs may break up (your code may result in `[ { name: ['newSales', 'oldSales'], data:[ 0,1 ] } ]`. Note that the values are swapped)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.entries()` and `Array#reduce()`:

```js
const obj = {
  newSales: 1,
  oldSales: 0
}
const dataSet=[]

dataSet.push(Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc,[key,value])=>{
  acc.name.push(key)
  acc.data.push(value)
  return acc
},{name:[],data:[]}));

console.log(dataSet);
```